# Get list of english fonts only

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a list of all english fonts and print some strings with them.

This is the code I use to create the images of the strings:

```
public static BufferedImage imageForString (String str, Font font) {

    font = new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), 400); //Can't trust people to size their own font -_-

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

    g2d.setFont(font);
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    int width = fm.stringWidth(str);
    int height = fm.getHeight();
    g2d.dispose();

    try {
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Problem printing: " + str + " " + "with font: " + font);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    g2d.setFont(font);
    fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString(str, 0, fm.getAscent());
    g2d.dispose();
    return img;

}
```

I'm trying to print every letter of the alphabet separately in every font the system has that is capable of displaying english text. That's obviously not working because  I keep getting exceptions thrown on the line I put the try/catch block around.

I'm using this to get a list of all fonts the system has (apparently it includes other languages?):

```
public static final Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
```

Here's the exception being thrown:

```
Problem printing: ' with font: java.awt.Font[family=Al Bayan,name=AlBayan,style=plain,size=400]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (601) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:999)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:326)
    at HashMaker.imageForString(HashMaker.java:48)
    at HashMaker.getImgs(HashMaker.java:69)
    at HashMaker.main(HashMaker.java:83)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(IntegerInterleavedRaster.java:201)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:911)
    at ImageUtils.colIsWhite(ImageUtils.java:23)
    at ImageUtils.parseImage(ImageUtils.java:40)
    at Letter.<init>(Letter.java:24)
    at HashMaker.main(HashMaker.java:85)`
```

It's not just the single quote, the exception is also thrown on latin characters such as a 'J'

Comment: Add a stacktrace. You are catching an exception from the `BufferedImage` constructor which has nothing to do with the font ability to display some characters. It is probably `IllegalArgumentException` about negative or zero width or height.

Comment: On topic, `Font` class has a bunch of methods named `canDisplay` and `canDisplayUpTo` that provide an explicit way to check whether a font can display a specific character or a set of characters.

Comment: Your `BufferedImage` is only 1 pixel big.

Comment: You probably mean latin fonts?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin edited for your suggestion, is there a more elegant solution than check if it can display every letter created by smashing my hand on my keyboard?

Comment: I have already mentioned `Font.canDisplay` family of methods which are intended just for that.

Comment: @PeterMmm No, that's how I find out the size the buffered image needs to be which is why I immediately dispose of it and create a new Buffered Image (int the try/catch)

Comment: @CommuSoft yes that's what I mean ;p

Comment: @OlegEstekhin there's no better way of finding out if a font supports a language than 

char[] arr = "~!@#$%^&*()_+`1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP{}|qwertyuiop[]\ASDFGHJKL:"asdfghjkl;'ZXCVBNM<>?zxcvbnm,./".toCharArray(); font.canDisplayUptTo(arr,0,arr.length)==-1

Comment: Try to convert that string into Char array and check it with char

Comment: @Krishna what do you mean? str.toCharArray() and g2d.drawChars()? What difference should that make?

Comment: @Alex just get Char array and check for the char a to z and you can separate array of english char.

Comment: @Krishna @ Oleg sounds like you guys have the same idea so if one of you wants to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Also, anyone have any clue why I was downvoted?

Comment: @Alex okey i did it and ya dont know why people downvote but no worry +1 for good question :)